# Create 2 separate tables for different folders using glue crawler in Athena DB

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-glue, amazon-athena

s3 path

[s3 bucket name]

|- mcc

|-- p1

|---- cl

|------ book3.csv

|---- ml

|------ book1.csv

|-- p2

|---- cl

|------ book4.csv

|---- ml

|------ book2.csv

Expected Athena DB tables

- ml
- cl

This is way files are store in s3 bucket I need to make a two tables for ml and cl, all csv file in ml folders have same columns and same for cl. Is there any way to create a two tables for all ml and all cl using glue crawler?

Book3 and Book4 have same schema and columns

Book1 and Book2 have same schema and columns

The s3 path
[s3 path image]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jt2qR.png "click here"